# pickle.dumps output size increases when input is generated using json.loads

Tags: python-2.7, pickle

In Python 2.7.16:

```py
import json
import pickle

list1 = [{u'key': 1}, {u'key': 2}]
list2 = json.loads('[{"key": 1}, {"key": 2}]')

pickle.dumps(list1)
# outputs '(lp0\n(dp1\nVkey\np2\nI1\nsa(dp3\ng2\nI2\nsa.'

pickle.dumps(list2)
# outputs '(lp0\n(dp1\nVkey\np2\nI1\nsa(dp3\nVkey\np4\nI2\nsa.'
```

Why is the output of `pickle.dumps` different for `list1` and for `list2`?

The output of `pickle.dumps(list1)` only contains the string `key` once, despite `key` being present in both list entries, so there appears to be some optimisation there. However, the output of `pickle.dumps(list2)` contains two instances of the string `key`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is due to string interning. In `list1`, both keys `"key"` are pointing to the same memory address because Python has interned the strings. In `list2`, the keys have different memory addresses, which suggests that `json.loads` does not do any string interning.

In case anyone has a similar use case to us (which is to minimise the memory footprint of an object loaded from JSON), `simplejson` appears to use string interning.